# How to make a Personal Browser-based dynamic GUI

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, browser

I have (my own) java App to control and monitor a model railway. Naturally its Swing based and the GUI changes dynamically as trains move around the layout. The GUI is (of course) tied to the monitor attached to the computer the App runs on which is wired to electronics on the layout.

Is it possible to rearrange things so that some windows can be opened remotely using a (WiFi-connected) browser, probably on a hand-held that does not support Java and without doing a Native App for each possible hand-held?

I need to draw, erase and move: text, lines and images. Each train is represented by a small image which moves pixel by pixel as the train moves so quite a few updates might be involved. See http://groups.yahoo.com/group/mergtcc/ for an example track diagram window.

Obviously changes occur without user interaction so the server (the present App plus possible extras) needs to send changes as they occur preferably without client polling.

I'd like to support several clients simultaneously - perhaps one hand-held device per train on the layout.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to build a web application that make extensive use of Ajax.

Comment: Don't put signatures on posts.  See the faq here- http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: [tag:java] is not the same as [tag:javascript]. Unless you are writing an applet (which never should be used), don't tag java

Comment: I know full well that Java is not the same as Javascript!! I am using Java at the server end. I might have to use javascript at the client end. I am not planning to use an Applet. Tagging Java seemed appropriate because I need Java at one end of the comms link. Try reading the question next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just braindumping:

Use html + javascript to dynamically reposition certain html elements which represent the trains. That should have excellent browser support. Making them move frequently enough to appear animated probably won't be a performance issue on most hand held devices. Using html canvas to draw the trains, is another option, with reasonably good support. I'm not sure what performs best.

Use socket connections. Browser support is spotty. The Socket.io project aims to provide a facade in front of the various ways to achieve socket-like connections in various browsers. Having socket.io's cross browser interface to build upon will probably be a huge time saver, and quality improver. I haven't used it, but it looks like they have a few java server side implementations, which seem up your alley.

Comment: Socket.io led me to jWebSocket which on the surface seems appropriate (though I am not sure yet whether Socket.io adds things I need, or whether it simply loses compatibility with Java). So I guess I'd need a simple web server that serves a fixed page for each App window, somehow link jWebSocket into my Java App (thats not too clear from the docs) and write a javascript to run on the clients.

Comment: see http://caniuse.com/websockets, socket.io has more fallback methods in the client side framework, so should offer better browser support. But, not all of it's methods have performance that's totally comparable to real sockets. And yes, your outline sounds correct.

Comment: I got this working a few years ago and added a web server thread using JSON and a javascript for the client end. Animation works pretty well and it can even pan the layout diagram keeping 'your' train central. (Belated) Thanks for the response.